# Load TreeView From List

Tags: c#, wpf

i got this XAML Code already (

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeViewSL" Margin="10,5,875,10" Grid.Row="1">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
            DataType="{x:Type OfflineSparepartEntities:ArtikelTreeNode}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding ArtikelTreeNode}"
            >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeText}"/>                                    
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>                            
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

I got 2 list which give me back the correct data:

```
//Data for Root Element
var root = svc.GetRootArtikelTreeNode(WebSLList, eqNr, LanguageCode.D);

//Data for Child
var _childNodes = svc.GetChildArtikelTreeNodes(WebSLList, eqNr, _childParentId, LanguageCode.D);
```

I already tried it with

```
 treeViewSL.ItemsSource = root.NodeText.ToList();
 treeViewSL.Items.Refresh();
```

but then i only get back this:

[image]

so only the root element splited..

How i get this in a normal TreeNode with a Root Node and Child Nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> treeViewSL.ItemsSource = root.NodeText.ToList();

seems very wrong to me, the Linq function **ToList()** on a string returns all chars in one list. If I understood your concept correctly, you want 1 root node and x child nodes. To accomplish that, all objects should have the same type. When you have a simple class (or interface) **TreeItem(Header : string, Childs : IEnumerable)**, you can just set the ItemsSource of the TreeView as a list of these and this code:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate [...] ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">
```

will link to the child collection. Then you can access the properties of that object inside the DataTemplate.

EDIT:
Here is a working example:

```
public class TreeItem
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TreeItem> Childs { get; set; }
}

    var items = new List<TreeItem>
    {
        new TreeItem
        {
            Header = "This is the root",
            Childs = new[]
            {
                new TreeItem {Header = "Child item 1"},
                new TreeItem {Header = "Child item 2"}
            }
        }
    };

    treeViewSL.ItemsSource = items;
```

Comment: how do you mean with Treeitem,Childs?

Comment: Just create a simple class with the property header (string) and Childs (IEnumerable<YourClassName>). Then do what I tell in the answer and see the result. After you understood how the TreeView in WPF works, you can apply this concept to your (view)model.

Comment: i created now Childs class with `string header;
        IEnumerable<ArtikelTreeNode> _aNode;` and set the itemssource, but of course now its empty

Comment: I now tested and your example work, but how i get the data of a List with 12 data in this Child Property, and how would i add then Child Item 1.1? Much thanks for your help till now!

Comment: there a princip in WPF called MVVM - Model View ViewModel. Your data is the model. The view is the treeview. You need to write the view model for your data which means that you have to write a wrapper which provides the information the treeview is able to handle. Just modify the working example and it should work.